# Wordpress: Getting Month by Month posts, issue with layout

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, archive

I've got an issue where I'm getting the wordpress posts month by month, but I'm missing something obvious where by it screws with my layout a bit. I'm using the 996 grid system for my layout.

**The NEED:**

I'm getting all posts in March 2013 and wanting to lay them out each inside a  so 3 posts are stacked like screenshot A. [image]

My code is below:

```
<div class="container clearfix" style="background:yellow;">
    <div class="grid_12" style="background:blue;">
        <?php
                $blogtime = date('Y');
                $prev_limit_year = $blogtime - 1;
                $prev_month = '';
                $prev_year = '';
                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 20,
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
                );
                $postsbymonth = new WP_Query($args);

                while($postsbymonth->have_posts()) {
                    $postsbymonth->the_post();
                    if(get_the_time('F') != $prev_month || get_the_time('Y') != $prev_year && get_the_time('Y') == $prev_limit_year) {

                        echo "<h2>".get_the_time('F, Y')."</h2>\n\n";

                        }
            ?>
    </div>

<div class="grid_4" style="background:red;">
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('standard-thumb'); ?></a>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    </article>
</div>

<?php
$prev_month = get_the_time('F');
$prev_year = get_the_time('Y');
}
    ?>
</div> <!-- END OF CONTAINER -->
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

With the above code, every single instance of grid_4 sits outside the container EXCEPT the first one. See Screenshot B[image]

How can I make sure all grid_4 divs are included inside the container?

I've tried moving the div which doesent work, I think I'm missing something fundamental from the query.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems if I remove the closing div to grid_4 - it now works...

In the dom it now all sits inside the container... however looking at the template markup code I'm one div short...

I don't know why this is happening but it is... one day I'll figure out why but right now wordpress is automagically adding an extra div.